# Erro ao emular o android via celular

Tags: conexão, emulador

Eu estou criando um `app` para `android` e estava emulando ele no meu celular,
estava tudo ok mas de um dia para outro apareceu essa mensagem :

**Erro**

> failed to connect to /192.168.0.103 (port 80): connect failed:
>   ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

Não consigo achar um resposta pra isso, por que usar o emulador no desktop esta fora de cogitação porque é muito lento.

Obrigado.

Comment: Só pra eu entender, você estava emulando ou usando num celular de verdade?

Comment: sim  no meu celular   que é pra emular mais rápido  tava rodando normal   mas paro do nada ...

Comment: Entao vc não está emulando, está executando o aplicativo no celular (se é que eu entendi direito).

Comment: sim   isso mesmo mas estava tudo certo  porem  de repente parou

Comment: Cheque se nas opções de programador,  opção de depurar via USB não desativou. Caso não funcione,  revogue as autorizações de depuração USB, replugue i cabobe veja se resolve.

Comment: esta tudo ok  na opcao depurar via USB   estava ativada ...   esta tudo  ok   desativei e ativei novamente   e nada   osso eim

Comment: Você pode usar o emulador nativo do Android, emular direto em um dispositivo móvel ou utilizar algum emulador especifico, como o GenyMotion. que tipo de app você está desenvolvendo? a sua pergunta está muito vaga... falta mais informação sobre o erro.

Comment: eu alterei um dado la no wamp que estava bloqueando o acesso aos diretórios...   ai deu certo ... mas somente em um dos celulares   estranhamente no outro ainda esta dando errado.. mas de qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda